# Not able to create .so file in httpd-2.4.18

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, .so, hp-nonstop

While I am installing httpd-2.4.18 on non stop hp, I am not able to create .so file in modules. It creates only .a file. But .so file is required in httpd.conf. How to create .so file ?

Comment: Please edit the question and show the steps you're following to do so. Otherwise, the only possible answer is a copy of the complete documentation you could Google yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the SHARED pragma (assuming you are coding in C or C++) to make a DLL. I think that corresponds to your ".so" file.